# How many points in a uniform n-dimensional grid can't be expressed as an integer multiple of another point in the grid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computational-geometry, discrete-optimization

Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional uniform grid.  Along each axis I have points from $0$ to some integer extent $L$.

Is there a closed form for the number of points that can't be expressed as a non-zero, integer multiple of another point in the grid, given $n$ and $L$?

For instance, in the 2D case for $L=10$:

$[2,1]$ would satisfy the condition but $[4,2]$ would not because it is an integer multiple of $[2,1]$.

A possibly helpful note:

If you already know the smallest vector along a possible direction in the grid, you can find how many other points along the same direction there are.  So for the point $[2,1]$ I know there are

$$
\left\lfloor\left(\frac{L}{\max\{x,y\}}\right)\right\rfloor-1=\left\lfloor\left(\frac{10}{2}\right)\right\rfloor-1=4
$$

integer multiples of $[2,1]$.  But if I knew those points *a priori* I wouldn't need to solve this problem.

Comment: "Not an integer multiple of another point" means the coordinates have greatest common divisor $1$.

Comment: Right.  Which means it's easy to check if any given point satisfies the condition, but given some large dimensional space, I want to see how many points satisfy the condition without looping through them all and checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2D your problem is related to the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).
In fact the geometrical rendering of this sequence is as sketched below.

[image: Farey_geom_1]

At level $7$ for example, you have all the ratios already contained in precedent levels (the small black points) plus
the newly added (big red points) $1/7, 2/7, \cdots, 6/7$.

In the Wikipedia article above you find all the explanation of how to count the number of terms in a Farey sequence of a certain level,
as well the difference with the previous levels, and I am not going to repeat it here.

As a matter of fact, in 2D a segment from the origin to the point$(X,Y)$ (assume wlog $0 \le Y \le X$) will not intercept an intermediate point with integral coordinates
if the fraction $Y/X$ is irreducible, i.e. if $\gcd (Y,X) =1$ , otherwise if $1 < \gcd (Y,X) =g$ then $(X,Y) = g (X/g, Y/g)$.
Also consider that $\gcd(Y,X) =\gcd(Y, X-Y)$, that is we can tilt the triangle above to have the right corner at the origin and count the points by diagonals $X+Y=n$.

Similarly in 3D, a segment from the origin to the point $(X,Y,Z)$ will not intercept any other point before if $\gcd(X,Y,Z)=1$, otherwise
we will have $(X,Y,Z)= g (X/g, Y/g, Z/g)$.

Same for higher dimensions, and again we can count the points by diagonal planes
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ {\left( {X_1 ,X_2 , \cdots ,X_m } \right)\;:\;\gcd \left( {X_1 ,X_2 , \cdots ,X_m } \right) = g\; \wedge \;\;0 \le X_1  \le X_2  \le  \cdots  \le X_m  \le L} \right\} =   \cr 
  &  = \left\{ {\left( {X_1 ,X_2 , \cdots ,X_m } \right)\;:\;\gcd \left( {X_1 ,X_2 , \cdots ,X_m } \right) = g\; \wedge \;\;0 \le X_1  + X_2  +  \cdots  + X_m  \le L} \right\} \cr} 
$$

The problem goes under the standard denomination of [visible lattice points](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html).

At the same time we can consider
$$
\left\{ {\left( {X_1 ,X_2 , \cdots ,X_m } \right)\;:\;\quad \gcd \left( {X_1 ,X_2 , \cdots ,X_m } \right) = 1\; \wedge \;\;X_1  + X_2  +  \cdots  + X_m  = n} \right\}
$$
as the set of the [Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $n$ into $m$ *relatively prime* parts,
the compositions being understood in the "weak" sense if $0 \le X_j$ and in the standard sense with $1 \le X_j$ .

Under this perspective, take a look at this interesting work by H.W. Gould
 ["Binomial Coefficients, the Bracket Function, and Compositions with Relatively Prime Summands"](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/2-4/gould.pdf).
Therein, having denoted by $ R_{\,m} (n)$ the number of standard compositions as above, i.e:
$$
R_{\,m} (n) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {1\, \le \,X_k }  \cr 
   {\gcd \left( {X_1 ,X_2 , \cdots ,X_m } \right) = 1}  \cr 
   {X_1  + X_2  +  \cdots  + X_m  = n}  \cr 
 } } \right.} 1 
$$
it is demonstrated that
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
R_{\,m} (n) = \sum\limits_{d\backslash n} {\left( \matrix{
  d - 1 \cr 
  m - 1 \cr}  \right)\mu \left( {n/d} \right)} 
 }$$
where $\mu$ denotes the Möbius function.

**Example**:

in 2D, the formula above gives 
$$
R_{\,2} (n)\quad \left| {\;2 \le n} \right.\;\; = \varphi (n)
 = {\rm 1}{\rm , 2}{\rm , 2}{\rm , 4}{\rm , 2}{\rm , 6}{\rm , 4}{\rm , 6}{\rm , 4}{\rm ,} \cdots 
$$

in 3D, we get
$$
R_{\,3} (n)\quad \left| {\;3 \le n} \right.\;\; =
 {\rm 1}{\rm , 3}{\rm , 6}{\rm , 9}{\rm , 15}{\rm , 18}{\rm , 27}{\rm , 30}{\rm , 45}{\rm , 42}{\rm , 66}{\rm , 63}{\rm , 84}{\rm , 84}
{\rm , 120}{\rm , 99}
$$
which is [OEIS A000741](http://oeis.org/A000741)

in 4D it is [OEIS A000742](http://oeis.org/A000742)

Comment: I think you may be right.  I think in 2D the number of allowed points is related to the number of terms in the Lth Farey sequence.

Comment: I expanded my answer to make you convinced that the key is the Farey sequence and thus the Totient function.

Comment: Yes.  I am now convinced the key is the Farey series and I have the answer for 2D.  Still trying to work out the solution for higher dimensions.

Comment: @Cogitator: well, honestly, the extension to higher dim. is not so straight. I found a precious article giving the formulas for that.

Comment: I haven't fully review the article yet, but I'm sufficiently convinced that this is close enough to the right track to award the bounty.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. Actually I am going to continue and work on it because it is an interesting question and that given above is just a first fundamental building block.

Comment: I don't know if it helps or if it is obvious, but it seems like as the number of dimensions increases, the fraction of points with gcd==1 approaches one.  Since I was interested in a high-D case, this approximate answer was sufficient for me.

Comment: Well, clearly the probability that $m$ coordinates share a common factor is decreasing with $m$. It is known that the density of visible numbers approaches $1/zeta(m)$ as $n \to \infty$ , re. for instance to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9903046v1)

Comment: @Cogitator: But note that the convergence is quite slow.